# Where can I find a Delphi online help better than the integrated one?

Tags: delphi, api, reference

Is ther any other documentation about delphi than the integrated help.

Something like the http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/ or the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/

...just for delphi.

Because imho the delphi help is <strike>badass</strike> bad.

Comment: Terminology note: *badass* means something is *really awesome*. It's not the same as *bad*.

Comment: @Rob: I was going to make the same comment.  I was a bit confused that if he was saying the Delphi help was *really awesome*, then why was he looking for other alternative help.

Comment: What version of Delphi? The help from Delphi 7 was quite good (although not perfect). The help from D2006 blew chunks. The help from D2007 is sort of adequate, if you don't mind the occasional trip into the VCL source or Google Land to find something that isn't documented. D2009's help is better than D2007's, but still has some holes in some areas.

Comment: @Ken, re: "blew chunks" - Thanks for that flash of memory lane (the nasty side).  I do agree with you; Help was once Delphi's leg up on the competition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really like Delphi Basics:

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/

So much so, that I paid him the $9 for the download version (and included a little extra), even though I usually use the online version anyway.

~~~

The only other one I keep a shortcut to on my desktop is the Delphi Wiki:

http://delphi.wikia.com/

It has a lot of valuable stuff, and goes into good depth on many topics as thousands have contributed to it. It's quite comprehensive, but will always have some missing parts - mainly because the world's Delphi knowledgebase is growing faster than anyone or any wiki can keep track of.

~~~

Then don't forget that books still (even in this online age) provide excellent reference tools that you can leisurely read and learn from.

My favorite Delphi author is [Marco Cantu](http://www.marcocantu.com/), and his books are excellent. I've started with Mastering Delphi 3 many years ago, and then went on to Mastering Delphi 5, Borland Delphi 2005, Delphi 2007 Handbook and Delphi 2009 Handbook.

Comment: delphi.wikia.com was started by Nick Hodges? I have been a long time contributor to it but I have never heard this before. I seem to remember some small changes contributed by Nick, and him talking about releasing the online help in wiki form (which never happened), but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks. I misread the Featured Article on the page thinking that Nick started the Wikia, whereas he actually only started the "Business Case" article. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Not that this really improves your situation any, but there is an online version of the [official documentation](http://docs.codegear.com/products/rad_studio/) offered from CodeGear.  They might have some additional resources there that you don't have yet.

Comment: I did not know about this...glad you mentioned it!

Answer (score 3):

You can download the chm (HTMLhelp file) versions of the Delphi Help too from the Codegear website. I've linked these in under my Tools menu and they open much faster than the latest help. It effectively gives you Delphi 7 help under D2009. Much better.

See Jim McKeeth's answer for the link to the CHMs.

On Vista/Win7, if the CHM files don't display properly, you may need to right-click on them, select "Properties", then click "Unblock".

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. 


I'm still trying to figure out why they went to the "Microsoft Document Explorer" disastrous approach in the first place.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Delphi PRAXIS published [Help Booster](http://www.delphipraxis.net/helpbooster.php?lng=en), which is a new front end for Delphi's built in help content, presumably without some of the speed issues and other quirks.  Works with DElphi 2006 and 2007.  Not sure about Delphi 2009 support.

Edit:
Here is some initial [support for Delphi 2009](http://tdelphihobbyist.blogspot.com/2008/03/delphi-help-booster.html).  Check out the second comment from the bottom.

Comment: Update: There are now a beta versions for Delphi 2009 and 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain [LearnDelphi.tv](http://LearnDelphi.tv) which has a large number of free videos on learning Delphi, however it's not very useful as a reference.  I have also started producing some commercially, which has been quite fun (but not yet profitable).  I currently have two produced (working on the third) and they cover VCL components in quite a lot of detail.

I can certainly recommend the books by [Marco Cantu](http://www.marcocantu.com/) and I have also purchased a few by [Bob Swart](http://www.drbob42.com/).  I'd also recommend [Delphi: ClientDataSets in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461008581) by Cary Jensen.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Source Code Adventures](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/58864), there seems to be a way to integrate Delphi 7 help with 2005/2006, and there is online documentation:

> The one gripe that some commenters
>   have raised, is that of documentation.
>   Here I have to say, they have a point.
>   For quite a while I actually had the
>   Delphi 7 help files on hand on my
>   development machine and there is [an
>   IDE expert](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23948) that you can download
>   that will allow you to use the Delphi
>   7 help files directly from the newer
>   IDE. The new help files are also
>   [available online](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/) though, and I
>   find Google is often better at finding
>   things that any table of contents is.

Answer (score 0):

sadly there are no official online help resources for Delphi, but there are some really good resources online, the best by far:
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/
http://delphi.about.com/